# Cardview in Androidx

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, cardview

So, the nupdate on Android studio does not have an inbuilt cardview and recyclerview dependencies in the gradle. whenever I try to include it or them( cause they are two), it gives me the following error;

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for 
':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:cardview:1.1.0
whenever I import it directly from the suggestions; 
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not determine artifacts for androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0: No cached version available for offline mode
```

Comment: `No cached version available for offline mode`. Show your `build.gradle` us

Comment: There is no `androidx.appcompat:cardview` artifact. The artifact name is `androidx.cardview:cardview` and the latest version (as of 2020-03-21) is `1.0.0`. See https://androidx.tech/artifacts/cardview/cardview/ for more.

Answer (score 0):

Add `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'` to your build.gradle file for using CardView